# define specific labels and create a table of contents of them

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing

I wanna create several labels with specific keyword and I use in text and after that, I create a table of content of this label to mention page that it is defined

For example, I wanna define this keyword

Namelist
And after that I wanna use it like this:

In page 5

Namelist: one

And in page 10

Namelist: two

And after that create a table of content like this:

One....5

Two....10

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The `tocloft` package enables the creation of new contents-like lists.

Read section **2.1 New list of...** in the manual (`> texdoc tocloft`) which explains how to do this. Try it, but if you have problems ask another question, including an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile which shows what you have tried.